# Calculating an integral containing a commutator for the hamiltonian and spin for a one electron atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

Problem:

> Calculate the following integral for a 1-electron atom
>
> $ < 2 p_x\alpha \,\, |\,\, [\hat{H},\hat{S_z}] \,\,|\,\, 2 p_x\alpha > $

This is my attempt at a solution:

$$ \, \hat{H}\hat{S}_z - \hat{S}_z\hat{H} \,\,|\,\,\,2 p_x\alpha > \,\,\,=\,\,|\,\, \hat{H}\hat{S}_z 2 p_x\alpha - \hat{S}_z\hat{H}2 p_x\alpha >$$ $$ =|\, \hat{H}(\frac{1}2 \hbar) 2p_x\alpha -\,\, \hat{S}_z(\frac{2{\hbar}^2}{2I})2 p_x\alpha > $$ $$ =|\, (\frac{2{\hbar}^2}{2I})(\frac{1}2 \hbar) 2p_x\alpha - (\frac{1}2 \hbar)(\frac{2{\hbar}^2}{2I})2 p_x\alpha > = 0$$

therefore $$ < 2 p_x\alpha \,\, |\,\, [\hat{H},\hat{S}_z] \,\,|\,\, 2 p_x\alpha > \,\,=\,\, 0 $$

Does that make sense as a solution?

Comment: What is the Hamiltonian in this case?

Comment: It wasn't given in the problem. I think since the problem stated it was a 1-electron atom, that we can use the rigid rotator model and say the Hamiltonian is $  \frac{\hat{L}^2}{2I}$.